# Predicting with random effects in mgcv gam

Tags: predictive-models, random-effects-model, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I am interested in modeling total fish catch using `gam` in `mgcv` to model simple random effects for individual vessels (that make repeated trips over time in the fishery). I have 98 subjects, so I thought I would use gam instead of gamm to model the random effects. My model is:

```
modelGOM <- gam(TotalFish ~ factor(SetYear) + factor(SetMonth) + 
 factor(TimePeriod) + s(SST) + s(VesselID, bs = "re", by = dum) + 
 s(Distance, by = TimePeriod) + 
 offset(log(HooksSet)), data = GOM, family = tw(), 
 method = "REML")
```

I have coded the random effect with bs = "re" and by = dum (I read that this would allow me to predict with the vessel effects at their predicted values or zero). "dum" is a vector of 1.

The model runs, but I am having problems predicting. I picked one of the vessels for the predictions (Vessel21) and average values for everything else except the predictor of interest for predictions (Distance).

```
data.frame("Distance"=seq(min(GOM$Distance), max(GOM$Distance), 
 length = 100), "SetYear" = '2006', "SetMonth" = '6',
 "TimePeriod" = 'A', "SST" = mean(GOM$SST),
 "VesselID" = 'Vessel21', "dum" = '0', 
                           #to predict without vessel effect
 "HooksSet" = mean(GOM$HooksSet))

pred_GOM_A_Swordfish <- predict(modelGOM, 
 grid.bin.GOM_A_Swordfish, type = "response", se = TRUE)
```

The error that I'm getting is:

```
Error in Predict.matrix.tprs.smooth(object, dk$data) : 
NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
In addition: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(xx, object$shift[i]) : - not meaningful for factors
```

I think this is being called because VesselID is a factor, but I'm using it a smooth for the random effects.

I have been able to successfully predict using gam without the simple random effects (bs = "re").

Can you provide any advice on how to predict this model without the VesselID term (but still include it in fitting)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From version 1.8.8 of **mgcv** `predict.gam` has gained an `exclude` argument which allows for the zeroing out of terms in the model, including random effects, when predicting, without the dummy trick that was suggested previously.

> - `predict.gam` and `predict.bam` now accept an `'exclude'` argument allowing terms (e.g. random effects) to be zeroed for prediction. For efficiency, smooth terms not in `terms` or in `exclude` are no longer evaluated, and are instead set to zero or not returned. See `?predict.gam`.

```
library("mgcv")
require("nlme")
dum <- rep(1,18)
b1 <- gam(travel ~ s(Rail, bs="re", by=dum), data=Rail, method="REML")
b2 <- gam(travel ~ s(Rail, bs="re"), data=Rail, method="REML")

head(predict(b1, newdata = cbind(Rail, dum = dum)))    # ranefs on
head(predict(b1, newdata = cbind(Rail, dum = 0)))      # ranefs off
head(predict(b2, newdata = Rail, exclude = "s(Rail)")) # ranefs off, no dummy

> head(predict(b1, newdata = cbind(Rail, dum = dum)))    # ranefs on
       1        2        3        4        5        6 
54.10852 54.10852 54.10852 31.96909 31.96909 31.96909  
> head(predict(b1, newdata = cbind(Rail, dum = 0)))      # ranefs off
   1    2    3    4    5    6 
66.5 66.5 66.5 66.5 66.5 66.5
> head(predict(b2, newdata = Rail, exclude = "s(Rail)")) # ranefs off, no dummy
   1    2    3    4    5    6 
66.5 66.5 66.5 66.5 66.5 66.5
```

### Older approach

Simon Wood has used the following simple example to check this is working:

```
library("mgcv")
require("nlme")
dum <- rep(1,18)
b <- gam(travel ~ s(Rail, bs="re", by=dum), data=Rail, method="REML")
predict(b, newdata=data.frame(Rail="1", dum=0)) ## r.e. "turned off"
predict(b, newdata=data.frame(Rail="1", dum=1)) ## prediction with r.e
```

Which works for me. Likewise:

```
dum <- rep(1, NROW(na.omit(Orthodont)))
m <- gam(distance ~ s(age, bs = "re", by = dum) + Sex, data = Orthodont)
predict(m, data.frame(age = 8, Sex = "Female", dum = 1))
predict(m, data.frame(age = 8, Sex = "Female", dum = 0))
```

also works.

So I would check the data you are supplying in `newdata` is what you think it is as the problem may not be with `VesselID` — the error is coming from the function that would have been called by the `predict()` calls in the examples above, *and* `Rail` is a factor in the first example.

Comment: Thank you, Gavin, for the examples! In working through those, I figured it out. You were correct - the error was in the newdata data frame. Once I removed the quotation marks around '0' for the "dum" by variable, I was able to predict without any errors. Rookie mistake, but I had been struggling with it all day and thought it was a problem with the VesselID factor being a smooth. Thank you so much!

Comment: How can one specify more than one random effect to exclude with `exclude`? I tried using `c()` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Using a vector of terms to exclude works for me: `exclude = c("s(x0)", "s(x2)")` say from the following model `b<-gam(y~s(x0)+s(I(x1^2))+s(x2)+offset(x3),data=dat)` from `?predict.gam` examples. You need to specify the strings in the vector passed to `exclude` with the notation used by `summary()` when displaying the information about each smooth term