# Get predictions from mgcv:gam model with a new level in a random effect smooth

Tags: r, random-effects-model, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

Is there a way to get a prediction from an gam model (from package mgcv) that contains random effect smooths, where the new data contains a level of the random effect that didn't exist in the training set?  Something comparable to the "re.form=NA" parameter in lme4:predict.merMod ?

```
library(hflights) # get a big data set
hflights$UniqueCarrier <- factor(hflights$UniqueCarrier) # turn carrier into a factor
newhflights <- head(hflights) # create "new" d.f. for prediction
newhflights$UniqueCarrier <- "ZZ" # change carrier to a previously unseen value 


library(mgcv)
m_gam <- gam(ActualElapsedTime ~ s(Distance) + s(TaxiOut, UniqueCarrier, bs="re"), data=hflights)
predict(m_gam, newdata=newhflights) # fails with "ZZ not in original fit"

library(lme4)
m_lmer <- lmer(ActualElapsedTime ~ Distance + (TaxiOut | UniqueCarrier), data=hflights)
predict(m_lmer, newdata=newhflights) # fails with "new levels detected in newdata"
predict(m_lmer, newdata=newhflights, re.form=NA) # works
```

I have searched for an answer and found this question, but it didn't appear to be directly related to my problem.  [Predicting with random effects in mgcv gam](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/131106/predicting-with-random-effects-in-mgcv-gam)
But I did try adding a dummy variable to the model based on it.

```
hflights$dummy <- 1
newhflights$dummy <- 0
m_gam <- gam(ActualElapsedTime ~ s(Distance) + s(TaxiOut, UniqueCarrier, bs="re", by=dummy), data=hflights)
predict(m_gam, newdata=newhflights) # still doesn't work, not in original fit
```

I'm out of ideas.  Am I overlooking something obvious?

Comment: I suppose refitting the model with `ZZ` added as a level to the original data is out of the question? (you'd need to refit with `drop.unused.levels = FALSE`). Alternatively, just set that new level to be one of the existing levels; as long as you've turned off the `re` term it will make no difference to the predictions (assuming the models are as per the ones shown).

Comment: The new previously unseen levels are not necessarily known until prediction time, and refitting the model is not a desirable option.  Overwriting the random effect level with a known one (then changing it back post-prediction) seems to work, and I guess that's the only real option.  It seemed awkward to do it that way, so I wondered if there was a more elegant solution.  Thanks!

Comment: No, even Simon Wood freely admits that handling of random effects is simple at best in `mgcv::gam`. Perhaps `mgcv::gamm` or `gamm4::gamm` might work better for you seeing as the spline fixed-effects part of your model appears relatively simple.